# HTTP download and multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, http, tcp

This may be a duplicate but I have not seen this being fully answered.

Does HTTP download throughput increase when using threads? 
My thinking is that when the TCP stack on the server is waiting for a ack from the receiver before sending the next chunk of data, another thread is sending out a request for data which is then serviced, leading to an increase in throughput.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is pretty much correct. Threading HTTP requests would increase throughput, up until the maximum number of connections was met on the server, and then this increase would plateau. The performance increase would be limited to both the server and the client computers threading abilities, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct only at the startup, during the transfer TCP has a dynamic window of data that can be sent without receiving an ACK.

So while the data transfer is going on, in most situations every chunk of data that can be sent is sent, resulting in maximum throughput.

When you use multiple threads you reduce the dead time in the TCP handshaking.
It can also be useful if you have to download files froms different servers or if the server limits the bandwidth per connection.